# Move to login screen if JWT does not exist React js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i need to move to login screen if user directly access a page this is what i have tried so far.

`if(token===''){router.push('/login')}`

Where am i wrong?

Comment: No only do you have to establish that there is a token you have to establish that it is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very trivial you should look around a bit. Anyways you can use useEffect to achieve this on your page like so in next js :

```
useEffect(()=>{
            if(!token){
                Router.push('/signin');
            }
    },[]);
```